# How to join with padded value for each group?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following data

```
CREATE TABLE list (
    entries TEXT[],
    category_id TEXT,
    group_id TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE cat (
    category_id TEXT,
    name TEXT
);
INSERT INTO list (entries, category_id, group_id) VALUES
 ('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}', 'c1',  'g1'),
 ('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}', 'c2',  'g1'),
 ('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}', 'c3',  'g2'),
 ('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}', 'c4',  'g2');
INSERT INTO cat (category_id, name) VALUES
 ('c1',  'Cat1'),
 ('c2',  'Cat2'),
 ('c3',  'Cat3'),
 ('c4',  'Cat4');
```

I would like to output

```
   entries                     cat_id  group_id
 ('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}', 'c1',  'g1'),
 ('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}', 'c2',  'g1'),
 ('[]',                        'c3',  'g1'),
 ('[]',                        'c4',  'g1'),
 ('[]',                        'c1',  'g2'),
 ('[]',                        'c2',  'g2'),
 ('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}', 'c3',  'g2'),
 ('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}', 'c4',  'g2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/queries-table-expressions.html) to produce a Cartesian product of categories and groups, then join them with the entries.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(entries, '{}') AS entries, 
    attrs.category_id, 
    attrs.group_id 
FROM
   (SELECT * FROM 
       (SELECT category_id FROM cat) cc
   CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT DISTINCT group_id from list) gg
   ) attrs
LEFT JOIN list lst ON
      attrs.category_id=lst.category_id
  AND attrs.group_id=lst.group_id
ORDER BY attrs.group_id, attrs.category_id;
```

Note: Groups are selected via the `list` table, but it's might good to normalize it a bit and move to a separate table (especially if there is more data related to a group)

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE to generate the `cross` of `(group_id, category_id)`:

```
with groupcats as (
  select distinct l.group_id, c.category_id
    from list l
         cross join cat c 
)
select coalesce(l.entries, '{}'::text[]) as entries,
       g.category_id as cat_id,
       g.group_id 
  from groupcats g
       left join list l
              on l.group_id = g.group_id 
             and l.category_id = g.category_id
 order by g.group_id, g.category_id;

          entries          | cat_id | group_id 
---------------------------+--------+----------
 {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}} | c1     | g1
 {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}} | c2     | g1
 {}                        | c3     | g1
 {}                        | c4     | g1
 {}                        | c1     | g2
 {}                        | c2     | g2
 {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}} | c3     | g2
 {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}} | c4     | g2
(8 rows)
```